# How to disable a DropDownListFor in MVC3 Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this working peace of code, which displays populate a DropDownList in my MVC3 Razor Web App.

```
       @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ReminderTime,
            new SelectList(Model.RemindersList, "Item1 ", "Item2"))
```

I would need keep the DropDownList populated but DISABLED it, so a User cannot select a value in the list.

Could you point me out in the right direction? Please provide me a sample of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

like this, by specifying the HTML Attributes. [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703436%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ReminderTime,
    Model.RemindersList,
    new { disabled = "disabled" }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your hit the wokring code in my specific case was             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ReminderTime,
                         new SelectList(Model.RemindersList, "Item1 ", "Item2"), new { disabled = "disabled" })

Comment: Please note that disabled form fields will not be submitted to the server.

Answer (score 1):

My solution thanks to Ravi hit

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ReminderTime,
                 new SelectList(Model.RemindersList, "Item1 ", "Item2"), new { disabled = "disabled" })
```